# Error in confusionMatrix.default: the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

When I was running a confusionMatrix (see code below) in caret, I encountered an error - confusionMatrix.default: the data cannot have more levels than the reference. I searched similar questions and did a few tests based on the online suggestion. However, I still cann't solve the problem.My goal is to use some feature set to predict Extroversion. Could anyone help me solve this problem. Thank you so much for your time.

Predictors <- Personality[PredictorNames]

SEXT <- Personality[2]

EXT <- cbind(SEXT, Predictors)

Control <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number =10, repeats =10)

ExtPart <- createDataPartition (EXT$sEXT, p = 0.70, list=FALSE)

Ext_Train <- EXT[ExtPart,]

Ext_Test <- EXT[-ExtPart,]

EXT.lm <- train(sEXT ~ ., data = Ext_Train, method = "lm", trControl = Control)

predictions <- predict(EXT.lm, Ext_Test,na.action = na.pass)

confusionMatrix(predictions, Ext_Test$sEXT)

## Tests I did:

**levels(predictions);levels(Ext_Test$sEXT)**

NULL
NULL

**length(predictions);length(Ext_Test$sEXT)**

[1] 73
[1] 73

**str(predictions);str(Ext_Test$sEXT)**

Named num [1:73] 3.54 2.82 2.54 3.19 2.14 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:73] "3" "5" "9" "11" ...

num [1:73] 4.3 3.7 3.65 3.35 2.6 3.35 4.3 2.3 2.5 4.33 ...

**summary(predictions);summary(Ext_Test$sEXT)**

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -5.377   2.701   3.172   3.005   3.861   5.405

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.750   2.710   3.300   3.343   3.800   4.950

Thank you again for your feedback.

**PS: I finally fixed the issue. Here is my solution.**

predictions <- predict(EXT.lm, Ext_Test)

Ext_u <- union(predictions, Ext_Test$sEXT)

Ext_table <- table(factor(predictions, Ext_u), factor(Ext_Test$sEXT, Ext_u))

dim(Ext_table)

confusionMatrix(Ext_table)

Comment: can you give us the output of your data set using the `dput()` function so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: I created a txt file using dput(). Would you like me to copy and paste the data here or upload the data here?

Comment: if it is small, put it in your question, otherwise put it in pastebin and link the pastebin here